# Prove a sequence is decreasing for AST.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am working on my Calculus two homework on the Alternating Sequence Test (AST).
I am asked if $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{({-1})^n({n^5})}{\sqrt{n^{11}+6}}$$
converges absolutely, conditionally, or diverges. Using the AST requires $$\frac{{n^5}}{\sqrt{n^{11}+6}} \geq \frac{{(n+1)^5}}{\sqrt{(n+1)^{11}+6}}$$
This seems true intuitively, but how would I go about proving this in a more robust way without simply graphing it or plugging in numbers?

If I proved that the $\frac{d}{dx} x^5 \leq \frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{(x^{11})+6}$, would that be sufficient enough to prove that the sequence is decreasing?

Thanks!

Comment: No differentiation required. Instead square both sides of the inequality to get rid of the root. Does that help?

Answer (score 5):

The inequality is preserved by squaring the terms, as they are positive, so we want:

> $$\begin{align}&\frac{n^{10}}{n^{11}+6}\ge\frac{(n+1)^{10}}{(n+1)^{11}+6}\\&\iff\frac{1}{n+6n^{-10}}\ge\frac{1}{n+1+6(n+1)^{-10}}\\&\iff n+6n^{-10}\le n+1+6(n+1)^{-10}\\&\iff n^{-10}-(n+1)^{-10}\le\frac{1}{6}\end{align}$$

And the latter can be verified easily using a variety of methods, e.g. $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n^{-10}-(n+1)^{-10})=0$ so there must exist an $N\in\Bbb N$ so that $\forall n\ge N, |n^{-10}-(n+1)^{-10}|=n^{-10}-(n+1)^{-10}\le 1/6$.

Note that we only need this monotonicity after a finite number of terms, so we do not care if $N$ is very big, just so long as it is finite (although as Jose' has shown, $N=2$ suffices).

Answer (score 3):

If $f(x)=\dfrac{x^{10}}{x^{11}+6}$, then$$f'(x)=-\frac{x^9\left(x^{11}-60\right)}{\left(x^{11}+6\right)^2},$$which is smaller than $0$ if $x>\sqrt[11]{60}\approx1.45$. Therefore $\bigl(f(n)\bigr)_{n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}}$ is strictly decreasing. And then so is your sequence.